# Python syntax error when installing npm component

Tags: python, npm

I am trying to install the following vue component via npm:

https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider

I am installing it as:

```
npm install vue-range-component --save
```

However, I am getting the following errors in the console:

```
> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/jovan/Desktop/work/projects/topgraphs/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/jovan/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:586:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.3.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jovan/Desktop/work/projects/topgraphs/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ vue-range-component@1.0.3
```

So, apparently, the component was installed, but there is some sort of syntax error in Python? Searching the internet for a solution, I have only found some references to different Python versions, but there is no mention of a version in the entire error output above. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: Can you install Python 2.7 for this one?

Comment: Well, I can, but it's strange that I would have to. I'll check what's going on with that package.

Comment: I think it's internally is using Python 2.7. Most Linux systems have it by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Python code given is only valid with python versions before python3.

```
import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

In python3 the `print` statement was made a function, so the parenthesis can't be left out. The package should be updated to use:

```
import sys; print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]);
```

.. instead.

Comment: I see. So, I can't fix this myself, since I'm already using the latest version of that package? And also, the error is not related to the new package I installed, but the node-gyp package?

Comment: I can't say - `node-gyp` is a build tool used for building packages; the error might be because of the package it's building or it might be internal node-gyp itself. You can't fix this yourself, outside of making `python2` the default python processor when you're installing the package (so that node-gyp uses python2 instead). I'd suggest making an upstream fix (i.e. a suggestion to the package maintainer where this error originates from) so that it works on both py2 and py3.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
print "string"
```

is not valid in Python 3+.

You have Python 3 but the library uses Python 2.7, so install that Python 2.7.